# Отслеживать координаты мыши C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно знать когда мышь будет у края экрана, после чего выполнить действие.Примерная конструкция такая:
    `if (ps.X < SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth && ps.X >= SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - this.Width && this.Background.ToString() == "#00FFFFFF")
                {
                    SetOpacityme(0.0, 1);
                }`

Так вот как ловить эти координаты? Таймер? Событие? Если можно то пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В WPF делается это не так.

1. Заведите UserControl, который будет уметь выполнять нужные вам действия.
2. Разместите этот контрол так, чтобы активная область совпадала с краем окна: либо положите один контрол в корень окна, а остальные внутрь со Margin'ами, либо 4 штуки UserControl'ов по боковым сторонам окна, Layout Manager вам в помощь.
3. Заведите в контроле [триггер на `IsMouseDirectlyOver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4564748/276994) или подпишитесь на `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave`.

Answer (score 0):

Событие MouseMove.В обработчике события проверять координаты курсора.